# Execute voltdb query from nodejs client

Tags: voltdb

I am trying to develop `voltdb` client in `nodejs` and have gone through [voltdb-client-nodejs](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-nodejs). The code very well explains how to call stored-procedures from nodejs client. However, I would like to know how can I run simple insert/read query without calling stored-procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the nodejs driver, you would call the built-in `@AdHoc` system procedure and pass in the SQL string as a parameter.  This is how most of our client libraries work.  The only exception I can think of is the JDBC driver, but even in that case, the CallableStatement API is just a wrapper for sending the SQL string to the `@AdHoc` system procedure.

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.